# C# Monodevelop List all IP addresses connected to your Server on port Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, xamarin, mono, monodevelop

I need to get IP addresses witch connected to my server on port on Ubuntu (for exmp: 5809).
For example in Ubuntu we have terminal command like this:

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :5809 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

Output results after this command:

- 97 114.198.236.100
- 56 67.166.157.194
- 44 170.248.43.76
- 38 141.0.9.20
- 37 49.248.0.2

How to realize analog of this function in C# Mono Ubuntu ?
I hope for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tezaurismosis - answered me in another forum, i'l thanks him.

```
var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = @"netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :80| awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

proc.Start();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    // каждая строка вывода
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}
```